# landing page on my laravel that says "<< HEAD >>

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

Hi anyone can help on what is the problem with this. There is a text that says "<<<<< HEAD >>>>>> baa168ef04df10a6b06390d10ae69ef359253a90"[image]

It is only shown on my live but on my local environment it doesn't show. Hoping you can help me.

Comment: Looks like a merge error. It's something in the code you deployed which we can't see.

Comment: Yep, that's a Git merge conflict you've accidentally committed somewhere.

Comment: Thank you yeah i check on it and it was on merge conflict.

Answer (score 2):

You have committed a Git merge error into your page.

View the file or view the Git repository and you will find that content in there.

Simply remove the merge conflict, by removing the Git merge error and replacing it with the part of the merge conflict which you want to keep.

TLDR;
Check your file and remove the content you don't want in there